# Mobile Development On A Pi

Tags: software-installation, c++, android, software-development, sdl

I've been using a raspberry pi for two years for coding ( mostly in c++, using SDL2 ). Now feeling I have a sufficient grasp of this library, I would like to try out it's mobile utilities to get stuff running on android phones.

What I've done up to now :

1. Of course, I googled "raspberry pi SDl2 mobile development" and only got raspberry pi forums links about using SDL2, but not about mobile stuff.
2. I checked out [Lazy Foo's tutorial](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/52_hello_mobile/android_linux/index.php), but I know that installing general debian code on raspberry pi usually is more complicated than just running `apt-get`. ( Once I tried installing Wine, resulting in overnight compilation for unusable binary ).
3. My experience with java related software and Raspbian has often ended in the OS'es premature reinstall.

Has anybody previously attempted this ? Any tips ?

I am currently using a raspberry pi 2 with Raspbian Jessie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [NDK download page](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html) only supports x86(-64) regardless of operating system.

I am 99% positive [the SDK](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads) is going to be a prerequisite, and in this case it doesn't appear to be be architecture specific -- although I think the current download page may be misleading in that regard.  However, `apt search android` reveals SDK and `adb` packages are available on Raspbian, so it may be plausible.  Except there is no mention of the NDK in that list.

$0.02: This is a crazy thing to want to do on any model of Raspberry Pi.  Maybe using it as an installer or for utility tasks via `adb` but as a development platform for this stuff it is not going to hold up.

Comment: You are right about the SDK, Lazy Foo talks about installing it in his tutorial. I know it's crazy to do mobile development on r-pi, but I still would like to try